# Why is nodemon unresponsive to any commands in terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation

I'm trying to use nodemon instead of nodejs, but it doesn't want to work.

There are no errors. The install goes smoothly and also returns no errors. If I type in ANY nodemon commands such as `nodemon myappname.js` ...nothing happens. At all. It won't even return nodemon version number when I type `nodemon -h` (or -help or --help). The command line simply returns to a new line. No feedback.

Why is nodemon unresponsive?

FYI, nodejs works just fine. The npm commands also appear to be fine. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

try `which nodemon` to find out if that command is already there. It should run by using `nodemon server.js`

Also make sure you run command in global mode `npm install nodemon -g`

Answer (score 0):

nodemon is not working because may be you have installed nodejs 14.17.5 LTS ,just uninstall it and try to use nodejs 16.6.2 Current latest features, it will certainly help and solve the problem of not working nodemon in terminal